# How can I find out the version of the running Memgraph docker instance?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I start Docker instance of Memgraph Platform I can see the following in CLI:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
Memgraph Lab is running at localhost:3000

mgconsole 1.1
Connected to 'memgraph://127.0.0.1:7687'
Type :help for shell usage
Quit the shell by typing Ctrl-D(eof) or :quit
memgraph>
```

When I connect with Memgraph Lab to that same instance I can see the version of Memgraph Lab.

So I can see that mgconsole is 1.1, Memgraph Lab is 2.0.1, but what about MemgraphDB? How can I see the version of MemgraphDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the MemgraphDB version by running the `SHOW VERSION;` command. The command is the same whether you are using mgconsole or Memgraph Lab